# Как разделать людей по User-Agent в django

Tags: python-3.x, django

Мне нужно чтоб при заходу на сайт выдавалось одно или другая страничка (приложение)
1.11

Comment: У запроса есть `request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT')`, читайте и делайте что хотите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно написать [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/), которой будет смотреть на User-Agent переданный в запросе и выдавать пользователю подходящий ответ.